Get Coords from LeafletMouseEvent
I am trying to get coords from a leaflet map. I tried using e.latlng but it only returns the coords i initialized the map with. Not sure what's not working honestly.
Here is my code:
  private map: L.Map;
  private centroid: L.LatLngExpression = [-31.4189903, -64.1741866];
  private marker: L.Marker;

  public initMap(): void {
    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: this.centroid,
      zoom: 12,
    });

    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      minZoom: 10,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });

    tiles.addTo(this.map);
   
    this.map.on("click", this.mapClicked.bind(this));
  }

  mapClicked(e: L.LeafletMouseEvent) {
    console.log('Click event: ', e)
    console.log(e.latlng)
  }
}

console.log(e.latlng) returns [-31.4189903, -64.1741866] no matter where I click on the map. I want to get the coords from the place I am clicking on.

Try this code:
map.on('click', 
                function(e){
                    var coord = e.latlng.toString().split(',');
                    var lat = coord[0].split('(');
                    var lng = coord[1].split(')');
                    alert("You clicked the map at latitude: " + lat[1] + " and longitude:" + lng[0]);
                });

